# Comparatively speaking, how computationally intensive is casting to `double` and back?

Tags: java

I've been playing around with the new `record` class type introduced in Java 14 and had a go at creating a Vector record. Ideally the Vector record wouldn't need to be rewritten for the various different primitives, but mixing Java generics with records has proven to be a bit complicated. since the type of primitive the vector contains is passed as the generic parameter, the type is not known at runtime and arithmetic cannot be done on the vectors the conventional way.

Here is my code:

```
public record Vector<T> (T... elements)
{
    public int magnitude()
    {
    return this.elements.length;
    }

    public static <T> Vector<?> add(Vector<T> addend1, Vector<T> addend2)
    {
    if (addend1.magnitude() == addend2.magnitude())
        if (addend1.elements instanceof Number[])
        {
        ArrayList<Double> elements = new ArrayList<Double>();

        for (int i = 0; i < addend1.magnitude(); i++)
        {
            elements.add(((Number) addend1.elements[i]).doubleValue() + ((Number) addend2.elements[i]).doubleValue());
        }

        if(addend1.elements instanceof Double[]) return new Vector<Double>(elements.toArray(Double[]::new));
        if(addend1.elements instanceof Float[]) return new Vector<Float>(elements.stream().map(e -> ((Number)e).floatValue()).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(Float[]::new));
        if(addend1.elements instanceof Integer[]) return new Vector<Integer>(elements.stream().map(e -> ((Number)e).intValue()).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(Integer[]::new));
        }

    return null;
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Vector<Float> vec = new Vector<Float>(7.5f, 4.5f);
    Vector<Float> vec2 = new Vector<Float>(8.5f, 5.5f);
    Vector<Float> vec3 = (Vector<Float>) Vector.add(vec, vec2);

    System.out.println(vec3.elements()[0]);
    }
}
```

Since each primitive (baring boolean) is an extension of the Number type, and I don't want to duplicate  code for each possible primitive, I cast each element to the Number type. But since the base class Number cannot perform arithmetic I get the value as a double (because to the best of my knowledge the range of a double encompasses all the possible values of the other primitives) and then finally I can perform the arithmetic.

My problem is (or the one I notice, anyways) that each element gets casted to a double in order to add the vectors together. With doubles taking up twice as much memory as a float or an integer, I'm worried about the overhead of casting floats and ints to doubles, albeit temporarily, merely to perform a quick calculation.

Two questions to end off on. Firstly, are other pre-existing vector implementations similar in this sense? I can't see any way around this other than rewriting the code for each primitive type and skipping the genric route entirely.

Secondly, if this is truly a horrible way to go about doing this, what is the actual overhead of casting to a double and back? In a published application, would the calculations happen so fast that there wouldn't be a noticeable increase in memory usage?

Comment: The use of `Vector` is going to be massively more expensive than the actual numeric conversions.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I suppose that answers my second question, but do you mean that about all implementations of a Vector or mine specifically? Perhaps you find fault with my use of varargs?

Comment: I misread and thought you were using the existing JDK class named `Vector`. I suggest avoiding reusing names from things in the JDK to avoid confusion.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Ehhhhhh.... I can't really bring myself to name vector data holder class anything other than Vector...